# Есть возможность сделать ссылку для отправки сообщения через email на опр. аккаунт?

Tags: email, браузер, gmail

Допустим, у меня есть аккаунт для связи. И я хочу указать его на своем сайте. Но я хочу указать его так, что бы при нажатии на него открывалась форма для письма, желательно в браузере. Я знаю, что для открытия клиента на пк можно указать `mailto:...`, но например на SO это не работает. С `https://mailto:...` просто открывается стартовая страница gmail.

Есть какой нибудь способ сделать это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылки `mailto` открывают настроенный на компьютере или в браузере почтовый клиент или веб-клиент по умолчанию. Спецификация поддерживается не всеми браузерами.

Это означает что при нажатии на вашу ссылку, клиента не обязательно направит на стартовую страницу gmail. Вместо этого, откроется настроенный им или предустановленный системой / браузером почтовый клиент. У пользователей IE оно и вовсе не будет работать.

Если хочется что бы каждый посетитель сайта видел одно и то же, форму письма придётся написать самому. Стоит однако учесть что вы не сможете отправить сообщение напрямую из JavaScript. Вместо этого придётся сделать одно из следующих:

- Использовать `window.open('mailto:test@example.com')`, который откроет почтовый клиент, аналогично тегу `mailto:` в html.
- Использовать сторонний API, например [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/signup/) напрямую из JavaScript. Ниже приведён пример вызова API Mаndrill через AJAX в jQuery (не забудьте предварительно зарегистрироватся на сайте Mandrill и получить API ключ):

  ```
  function sendMail() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
    data: {
      'key': 'API КЛЮЧ ТУТ',
      'message': {
        'from_email': 'ОТПРАВИТЕЛЬ@mail.com',
        'to': [
            {
              'email': 'ПОЛУЧАТЕЛЬ@mail.com',
              'type': 'to'
            }
          ],
        'autotext': 'true',
        'subject': 'ТЕМА ПИСЬМА',
        'html': 'СОДЕРЖАНИЕ ПИСЬМА (ПОЛУЧЕННОЕ ИЗ ВАШЕЙ ФОРМЫ ВВОДА)'
      }
    }
   })
  }
  ```

  Подобное одноко не рекомендуется делать, так как ваш API ключ будет виден всем посетителям вашего сайта, вместе с JavaScript кодом.
- Отправить запрос на отправление письма на ваш веб сервер, который за тем перенаправит email письмо на почтовый сервер. В таком случае, API ключ будет содержатся в коде веб сервера, а значит спрятан от посторонних глаз. Данный подход является рекомендуемым. [Ссылка на npm пакет для работы с API Mandrill из Node.js и примером использования](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mandrill). Если вы используйте что-то другое в качестве сервера, подход остаётся тот же.

P.S. Боты сканируют сайты в поисках email адресов для добавления в базы спам рассылок. Будьте готовы к тому что будете получать достаточно много спама, а лучше выделите отдельный email адрес для этого.

Comment: А есть способ для SO? Дело в том, что на SO это не работает(наведите курсор на мою автарку, вы не сможете открыть почту, хотя там стоит mailto: ) А JS я тоже не могу туда вставить.

Comment: Это запрещено. О том почему можно почитать [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105360/allow-mailto-in-the-user-card).

Comment: Однако, это всё ещё можно сделать используя сторонние сервисы. [www.is.gd](https://is.gd/) конвертирует ваш email адрес в обычный http url который можно вставить в карточку как обычную ссылку (можно сделать так что бы внешне это всё ещё выглядело как обычный email адрес).

Comment: Стоит однако учесть что не все положительно отнесутся к подобному решению. Короткие ссылки банятся некоторыми сервисами, системами и даже странами. Подробнее [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_URL).

Comment: Спасибо, все понял.

Comment: Но кстати, ТАМ, в принятом ответе, как раз таки написано, почему это не должно быть запрещено.

Comment: А is.gd хоть конвертирует емаил, но он автоматически подставляет туда http. И получается, что у меня есть http:// email@.com, как раз таки его я могу вставить на SO, и что как раз таки мне не нужно, т.к. перенаправляет на начальную gmail, а не на мою почту.